# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS in android studio

Tags: java, android, .net, android-studio, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement SignalR library on android studio and i have included jar files in lib folder. I am facing issue while installing the app in any device.

Session 'app': Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

I have tried available solutions but they did not worked out for me. 
Like.

including this

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x64', 'armeabi-v7a' , 'x86_64'
        universalApk true
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can go away by changing debug state into release in your android studio version.

Comment: I don't think so